# How to fix " implicit declaration of function"

Tags: c, header-files

I'm working on a GUI library in C for a school work, but I've got a problem with header files (I think).
I have a function "rectangle_coordinates" in a "draw.c" file, with the adequate "draw.h" header file, and in a file "widget_frame.c" I call this function, after including the "draw.h" header file.
But I still got a warning :

```
./src/ei_widget_frame.c:40:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rectangle_coordinates' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     rectangle_coordinates(&frame_to_draw, &xmin, &xmax, &ymin, &ymax);
```

Do you have an idea that can fix my problem ?

Comment: Check if you mispelled the name of the function.

Comment: You might want to post the relevant parts of `draw.h` and `draw.c`.

Comment: You get rid of the "implicit declaration" warning by explicitly declaring the function in a header that your code includes.  If the function is not `static`, it should be declared in a header for the other files that use it to include. Or you declare it in the file where it is defined and used (and it is therefore `static`) before you call it.  Or define it in the file before you call it (it's still `static`).  Do you have `rectangle_coordinates()` declared in `draw.h`?  Do you include `draw.h` in `ei_widget_frame.c`?

Comment: if you haven't misspelled the name you haven't included the right header. Show us the command you used to compile, the folder structure with the files in it and the part where you include headers

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, all things below should be verified and corrected (if needed).

1. The function name must be the same in all places (check for typo's).
2. The return type must be the same in all places.
3. The parameters list must be the same in all places.

In `draw.h` you should have something like:

```
extern /type/ rectangle_coordinates(&frame_to_draw, &xmin, &xmax, &ymin, &ymax);
```

where:

- /type/ is the return type of the function.
- the parameters list needs to be written correctly (I just made copy / paste from the warning message provided).

In both `draw.c` and `ei_widget_frame.c` you should have:

```
#include "draw.h"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was an error in the function name